# How can singleton hamper testability

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I read that singletons is bad for testability. Can you elaborate on this. Can't a singleton be mocked? They write due to tight coupling but I can't see to seem why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you're using the singleton and whether that singleton implements an interface. If the fact that it's a singleton is an *implementation detail*, then that's probably okay. If you're using its singleton nature in the code you want to test, that's more of a problem.

Take my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project for example. It has an `IClock` interface representing "a way of getting the current time". That has an implementation called `SystemClock` which is a singleton. Now consider some code using it:

```
public class BadClass
{
    public bool IsIt2016Yet()
    {
        var now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
        return now.InUtc().Year >= 2016;
    }
}
```

We can't test that code without somehow changing what `SystemClock.Instance` does. That code is *tightly coupled* to the singleton class. However, consider this:

```
public class GoodClass
{
    private readonly IClock clock;

    public GoodClass(IClock clock)
    {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public bool IsIt2016Yet()
    {
        var now = clock.Now;
        return now.InUtc().Year >= 2016;
    }
}
```

Now you're fine - in your production code you set up dependency injection to use `SystemClock.Instance` everywhere you want an `IClock`, but in testing code you can use a fake clock - such as the one provided in the `NodaTime.Testing` package. In production the code will end up using the singleton, but it's not tightly coupled to it.

That's assuming you have dependency injection suitably set up, of course. If you want to be able to just construct an instance anywhere without caring about the fact that it needs a clock, you could go for an option which *optionally* couples the class to the `SystemClock` singleton:

```
public GoodClass(IClock clock)
{
    this.clock = clock;
}

public GoodClass() : this(SystemClock.Instance)
{
}
```

Now it's still testable (and generally flexible) because you *can* pass in a clock, but it's convenient as it effectively "defaults" to the system clock. (You could do this with optional parameters and make an argument of `null` end up using `SystemClock.Instance` as another alternative.)

Comment: Reading again your example, this also is true for non-singleton classes. I mean, I can replace the singleton class in your sample by a non-singleton class and I think the issue you mentioned will still be there. If that is the case, then why explicitly say singleton is bad. I'm pretty sure i'm missing something that is probably why i'm confused.

Comment: @g_b: Singleton classes are probably more often accessed via their static retrieval method, basically. I'd also be wary of singletons which aren't really *natural* singletons, e.g. configurations. There's really, really only one system clock in a system, but you can imagine multiple configurations existing.

Comment: @g_b: More broadly though - yes, code can always be tied to concrete types, and that makes it harder to test. But non-singleton concrete types are generally easier to manage than singletons in terms of creating different instances with different test data.